# Changing index name in winlogbeat

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to change index name from winlogbeat. This is my yml file:
[image]

But still getting this error: Exiting: error loading template: failed to put data stream: could not put data stream:
`400 Bad Request: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no matching index template found for data stream`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the version of metricbeeat and elasticsearch?

Comment: Also could you replace the screenshot by a snippet of code ?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-a-data-stream.html#create-component-templates):

> A data stream requires a matching index template.

It seems your index name does not match any available template on your cluster.

## Solution:

Follow the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-a-data-stream.html#create-component-templates):

Create an ILM policy

```json
PUT _ilm/policy/winlog-lifecycle-policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_primary_shard_size": "50gb"
          }
        }
      },
      "warm": {
        "min_age": "30d",
        "actions": {
          "shrink": {
            "number_of_shards": 1
          },
          "forcemerge": {
            "max_num_segments": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "cold": {
        "min_age": "60d",
        "actions": {
          "searchable_snapshot": {
            "snapshot_repository": "found-snapshots"
          }
        }
      },
      "frozen": {
        "min_age": "90d",
        "actions": {
          "searchable_snapshot": {
            "snapshot_repository": "found-snapshots"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "735d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then create a template matching your index name:

```json
PUT _index_template/my-index-template
{
  "index_patterns": ["my-data-stream*"],
  "data_stream": { },
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "lifecycle": {
        "name": "winlog-lifecycle-policy"
      }
    }
  },
  "priority": 500,
  "_meta": {
    "description": "Template for my winlog data"
  }
}
```

and a template matching your index/datastream name.